# Uso da interface Consumer

Tags: java, interface

Qual a vantagem de ultilizar a interface `Consummer` do java dessa maneira?

Exemplo: tenho uma classe `UsuarioConsummer` que implementa a interface `Consummer` e chama seu metodo `acept`, segui o exemplo:

```
public class UsuarioConsummer implements Consumer<Usuario> {
    @Override
    public void accept(Usuario u) {
        System.out.println(u);  
    }
}
```

Depois criei uma classe `Usuario` com alguns atributos para testar essa classe e criei dentro do main alguns usuários dentro de uma lista. Para imprimir eu criei um método que recebe uma lista de `Usuario` e chama a classe `UsuarioConsummer`:

```
private static void teste01(List<Usuario> usuarios) {
Consumer<Usuario> usuarioConsumer = new Consumer<Usuario>() {
            @Override
            public void accept(Usuario u) {
                System.out.println(u.toString());
            }
        };
        usuarios.forEach(usuarioConsumer);
        usuarios.forEach(System.out::println);
    }
```

Porém, para imprimir eu não precisaria de todo esse aparato se fizesse desta maneira:

```
usuarios.forEach(u -> System.out.println(u));
```

Qual a diferença desta duas maneira de imprimir a lista?

Comment: Olá, Edson. Bem-vindo ao [pt.so]! Na verdade sua dúvida é sobre o uso de lambdas e não sobre a interface `Consumer`. Os dois códigos são equivalentes e os lambdas são apenas uma forma mais simples de evitar todo aquele código para implementar a interface, o que chamamos de açúcar sintático.

Comment: Obrigado pelo feedback, realmente e bem mais simples e enconomiza-se muitas linhas de código, mas existe algum cenario em que precisamos usa o Consummer ? Ou não ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Implementar um **Consumer**(ou qualquer outra interface funcional), em uma classe própria para isto, de forma centralizada, tem por vezes sua utilidade, como não espalhar o mesmo código em diversos pontos, pricipalmente quando você tem *statement lambda* e não apenas uma expressão lambda simples.

Considerando seus exemplos, por serem triviais, eles realmente não nos mostram melhoria nenhuma. Além disto, nos seus exemplos não é necessário explicitar o corpo como o fez - mesmo se for centralizar a implementação - lambdas tiraram essa verbosidade de java, então quando você tem um interface funcional você não precisa explicitar a assinatura do método implementado.

Alguns exemplos de vantagem em implementar um [`Consumer`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/function/Consumer.html)(ou qualquer outra interface funcional) são:

- interfaces funcionais próprias, com um ou mais métodos (apenas um não default, obviamente). Nestes casos você pode querer centralizar a implementação.
- usar o *consumer*/*supplier*/função/etc. para fazer coisas repetitivas em alguns pontos do código, como isto:

```java
public static void main(String[] args) {
    final Consumer<Usuario> printName = Usuario::printName;

    final Usuario u1 = new Usuario();
    u1.name = "Bruno";

    final Usuario u2 = new Usuario();
    u2.name = "César";

    printName.accept(u1);
    printName.accept(u2);
}

private static class Usuario {

    String name;

    void printName() {
        System.out.println(name);
    }

}
```

Ou seja, estamos aplicando o mesmo consumer (novamente, pode ser qualquer interface funcional) a diversos objetos, em determinandos contextos isto é interessante.

Isto é muito útil quando temos funções que aplicamos em diversos pontos e centralizando, ou seja, funçõe constantes, algo assim:

```
public interface MathFunctions {

    Function<Integer, Integer> funcMultiplicaPor2 = x -> x * 2;

}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println(MathFunctions.funcMultiplicaPor2.apply(4));
    System.out.println(MathFunctions.funcMultiplicaPor2.apply(8));
}
```

- mesma implementação funcional em diversos pontos: imagine que você tenha um `Consumer` mesmo queo trabalho que ele faça seja o mesmo em diversos pontos do código, algo assim:

```java
usuarios.forEach(u -> {
    u.ativar();
    u.setDataHoraAtivacao(LocalDateTime.now());

    // mais alguma coisa
});
```

Ao invés de espalhar isto pelo código você pode ter um `Consumer`(ou, novamente, qualquer outra interface funcional) em `Usuario` e apenas referenciá-la:

```
final Consumer<Usuario> ATIVACAO_CONSUMER = u -> {
    u.ativar();
    u.setDataHoraAtivacao(LocalDateTime.now());

    // mais alguma coisa
};

usuarios.forEach(Usuario.ATIVACAO_CONSUMER);
```

Este tipo de coisa é útil quando temos [`Function`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/function/Function.html) que referenciamos em várias partes, como casos que temos uma função para mapear um tipo genérico **T** para um outro tipo, por exemplo. Outro caso é quando temos um [`Comparator`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html) que não o padrão implementado, algo assim:

```
public static final Comparator<Usuario> USUARIO_COMPARATOR = Comparator.comparing(Usuario::getNome).thenComparing(Usuario::getCPF);
```

Para usar assim:

```
final Set<Usuario> usuarios = usuarios.stream().sorted(Usuario.USUARIO_COMPARATOR).collect(Collections.toSet());
```

Obs.: perceba que isto é um exemplo, neste caso pode ser melhor um método que faça as coisas de ativação ;)

Em resumo: vai depender muito do que você está usando, normalmente afeta apenas organização do código mesmo, práticas pessoais, etc., do contrário você não precisa implementar explicitamente tais interfaces. Em grandes aplicações você pode decidir por tem um projeto só de interfaces funcionais (como predicados e operadores) que são compartilhadas pela aplicação, coisas utilitárias e tal.

---

Um outro ponto que vi, que talvez você ainda não esteja habituado (mesmo tendo usado acima), neste seu exemplo:

```
usuarios.forEach(u -> System.out.println(u));
```

Você não precisa usar uma expressão lambda, pode usar *method reference*:

```
usuarios.forEach(System.out::println);
```

Neste caso você está referenciando um método estático que recebe como argumento o parâmetro do tipo do `Consumer` informado, inferido pela coleção.

Comment: Obrigado por sua resposta tirou minha dúvida, obrigado a todos que dedicou um tempo para responder minha pergunta.